# How can I make this styling work for button rather than an anchor?

Tags: html, css

i have my link that was styled, but when I change link tag to button in html and css styling won't work. How can get that styling on button type submit **note** I can't get link to submit via js because of interference with stripe that's why i wanna get this one working
**a styling that is working**

```css
a.animated-button:link:after, a.animated-button:visited:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    width: 150%;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
}
a.animated-button:link:hover, a.animated-button:visited:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: none;
}
a.animated-button:link:hover:after, a.animated-button:visited:hover:after {
    height: 450%;
}
a.animated-button:link, a.animated-button:visited {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto 0;
    padding: 14px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size:12px;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
    letter-spacing: .08em;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
a.animated-button.thar-three {
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}
a.animated-button.thar-three:hover {
    color: #000 !important;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-shadow: nthree;
}
a.animated-button.thar-three:hover:before {
    left: 0%;
    right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
a.animated-button.thar-three:before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    color: #000 !important;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);

}
```

```html
<a  href="" class="btn btn-sm animated-button thar-three">{% trans "pay" %}</a>
```

**button styling that won't work**

```css
button[type=submit].animated-button:link:after, button[type=submit].animated-button:visited:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    width: 150%;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
}
button[type=submit].animated-button:link:hover, button[type=submit].animated-button:visited:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: none;
}
button[type=submit].animated-button:link:hover:after, button[type=submit].animated-button:visited:hover:after {
    height: 450%;
}
button[type=submit].animated-button:link, button[type=submit].animated-button:visited {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto 0;
    padding: 14px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size:12px;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
    letter-spacing: .08em;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
button[type=submit].animated-button.thar-three {
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}
button[type=submit].animated-button.thar-three:hover {
    color: #000 !important;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-shadow: nthree;
}
button[type=submit].animated-button.thar-three:hover:before {
    left: 0%;
    right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
button[type=submit].animated-button.thar-three:before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    color: #000 !important;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);

}
```

```html
<button type="submit" href="" class="btn btn-sm animated-button thar-three">{% trans "pay" %}</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since a div is not a link, you can't use the selectors `:link` nor `:visited`. By simply removing them from your css, the result is way closer. Of course, you may have to implement a method to replace the use of `:link` and `:visited`

```css
button[type=submit].animated-button:after, button[type=submit].animated-button:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
}
button[type=submit].animated-button:hover, button[type=submit].animated-button:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: none;
}
button[type=submit].animated-button:hover:after, button[type=submit].animated-button:hover:after {
    height: 450%;
}
button[type=submit].animated-button, button[type=submit].animated-button {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto 0;
    padding: 14px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size:12px;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
    letter-spacing: .08em;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
button[type=submit].animated-button.thar-three {
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}
button[type=submit].animated-button.thar-three:hover {
    color: #000 !important;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-shadow: nthree;
}
button[type=submit].animated-button.thar-three:hover:before {
    left: 0%;
    right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
button[type=submit].animated-button.thar-three:before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    color: #000 !important;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);

}
```

```html
<button type="submit" href="" class="btn btn-sm animated-button thar-three">{% trans "pay" %}</button>
```

Comment: yeah thats better